# how to change the code of maven dependency using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have a project which is using several components to perform the functionality.All the components are managed by maven dependency control.now i want to change the code of one of the component just to enhance the functionality.That component is visible to me in eclipse project explorer i can access the files present in that component.But when i change the code in component,that change is not accessible to main project which is using that component as dependency.i have tried      maven:clean , update dependencies but nothing works.i am just new to maven so i am sure i am missing something.

any help is really appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Did you release a new version of the changed component? (is it included as a release or a snapshot dependency)

Comment: a new version 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Is the component built in the same project (i.e. a multi module build) or in a separate one?

Comment: Did you run clean install in both of them? You should run clean install to the changed component first then clean install to your main project.

Comment: You might have the same module available to maven and eclipse as a compiled jar in .m2. In this case it will be down to which version matches better your project reuquirements. Assuming you have the current trunk/snapshot checked out, your project might be pinned to an earlier fixed version in the pom and thus eclipse will not use updated trunk. If this is the case, unpin the version or set it to current trunk/snapshot.

Comment: @Henry component is in separate project

Comment: @OlegS. when i try to update the dependency in pom.xml,current verion is showing the jar file of 4k,whereas previous jar that comes from repository is of 14k.So when i set it to use the latest jar,my project is not compiling

Comment: @user3300629 Unfortunately I cannot advise you on that. But the fact the project compiles yet updates in the source do not lead to changes in the behaviour means that Eclipse gets the dependency not from your source and from elsewhere -- this is regulated by the version number in `<dependency>` in pom. Sorry I cannot be of more help

Answer (score 1):

When using maven with eclipse, dependencies can be used either directly as jar (as they were downloaded from the repositories) or, if the dependency is also defined in a project open in the same workspace, eclipse should use this project instead of the original jar.

You should check :

- that "disable workspace resolution" is not checked (when your right-click on your project in the project explorer, in the "maven" sub-menu).
- that in your project properties, in the "Java Build Path"( "Librairies" tab ) eclipse displays your dependency as a project and not as a jar from the local maven repository.

Also be careful to rename the component (and to publish it somewhere or to include the modified code in your project) to make sure that another developer building the project use the same modified dependecy and not the original one.

Comment: In my java build path eclipse is displaying my dependency as jar file not as a project...

Comment: @user3300629 : ok that explains your problem then. Can you confirm that "disable workspace resolution" is not checked ? If it's not, it means that you have a typo somewhere in your dependency definition.

Comment: @user3300629 then the module is not defined exactly the same way in it's pom and as a dependency in the main project's pom. Double check groupId, artifactId and version and try to change these on both sides.

Comment: i check groupId,artifactId and version theses are same

Comment: @user3300629 and have you tried to change them on both side as I advised you ?.... If you change them, Eclipse will not be able to use the jar as a dependency as this will not be available in your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

After you updated pom file with dependency, have you tried maven install ?